# Compiler error when passing a binary_function to inner_product inside another function

Tags: c++, c++11, std

The following code:

```
$ cat test02.cpp
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct myadd :
    public std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>
{
    std::string operator () (const std::string& x,const std::string& y) const {
        return x+" "+y;
    }
};

struct mymul :
    public std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>
{
    std::string operator () (const std::string& x,const std::string& y) const {
        return x+y;
    }
};

std::string spliceme(
    const std::list <std::string>& list1,
    const std::list <std::string>& list2,
    const std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>& add,
    const std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>& mul
) {
    return std::inner_product(list1.cbegin(),list1.cend(),list2.cbegin(),
        std::string(""),add,mul);
}

int main() {
    std::list <std::string> list1;
        list1.emplace_back("First");
        list1.emplace_back("Second");
        list1.emplace_back("Third");
    std::list <std::string> list2;
        list2.emplace_back("Foerst");
        list2.emplace_back("Annen");
        list2.emplace_back("Tredje");

    std::string result = spliceme(list1,list2,myadd(),mymul());
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Generates the compiler error:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test02.cpp -o test02
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/include/g++-v4/numeric:62:0,
                 from test02.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_numeric.h: In function '_Tp std::inner_product(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _Tp, _BinaryOperation1, _BinaryOperation2) [with _InputIterator1 = std::_List_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >, _InputIterator2 = std::_List_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _BinaryOperation1 = myadd, _BinaryOperation2 = std::binary_function<const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&, std::basic_string<char> >]':
test02.cpp:29:101:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_numeric.h:218:2: error: no match for call to '(std::binary_function<const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&, std::basic_string<char> >) (const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&)'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The issue occurs on the line:

```
return std::inner_product(list1.cbegin(),list1.cend(),list2.cbegin(),
    std::string(""),add,mul);
```

If I instantiate the classes myadd and mymul directly:

```
return std::inner_product(list1.cbegin(),list1.cend(),list2.cbegin(),
    std::string(""),myadd(),mymul());
```

Everything compiles and runs correctly.  What's wrong with the way I'm passing in the functions add and mul into the function spliceme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either this:

```
std::string spliceme(
  const std::list <std::string>& list1,
  const std::list <std::string>& list2,
  const std::function<std::string(const std::string&,const std::string&)>& add,
  const std::function<std::string(const std::string&,const std::string&)>& mul
) {
  return std::inner_product(list1.cbegin(),list1.cend(),list2.cbegin(),
    std::string(""),add,mul);
}
```

or this:

```
template<typename Add, typename Mul>
std::string spliceme(
  const std::list <std::string>& list1,
  const std::list <std::string>& list2,
  const Add& add,
  const Mul& mul
) {
  return std::inner_product(list1.cbegin(),list1.cend(),list2.cbegin(),
    std::string(""),add,mul);
}
```

makes your code work.  The first uses type erased functions, the second uses `template` functors.  The first lets you split your body out of the header, the second allows for improved inlineing.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string spliceme(
    const std::list <std::string>& list1,
    const std::list <std::string>& list2,
    const std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>& add,
    const std::binary_function
        <const std::string&,const std::string&,std::string>& mul
)
```

should be:

```
std::string spliceme(
    const std::list <std::string>& list1,
    const std::list <std::string>& list2,
    const myadd& add,
    const mymul& mul
) {
```

because operator() is not virtual function

Comment: I would like to be able to pass in arbitrary binary functions and not just myadd and mymul.

Answer (score 1):

`std::binary_function` was a convenience template for adding three typedefs to your function object.  It was never intended to be used as a base class in function signatures, because all that happens is your object gets sliced.  It has been deprecated in C++11 and should no longer be used.  Yakk gives a great answer on what you should be doing.  If you really need those typedefs (`first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`), add them yourself.